# superclass mismatch error from class in Trailblazer operation when making changes to Rails code while server is running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-cells, trailblazer

I'm using the `Trailblazer` gem with Rails, and there's a `Cell` class inside one of my `Trailblazer` operations that starts throwing a `superclass mismatch` error whenever I change the code with the server running.

If I start the server and immediately start navigating the site, everything runs fine.

However, if change some code any time after starting the server, and then try to load a page on the site, I get a `superclass mismatch` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the name of my operation was not the same as the name of the file I created for the operation. I had recently changed the filename from `register.rb` to `make_reservation.rb`, but hadn't changed the operation class name from `Register` to `MakeReservation`. When I made the class name change as well, the `superclass mismatch` error stopped happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you are toying with the Trailblazer book with **Rails 5-pre** you would need to watch out for the change in name spacing. Not having the name spacing properly resulted in a similar error.

Although in Rails 4, models inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` in Rails 5 it is form `ApplicationRecord`.

Your `app/concepts/thing/operation.rb` in my case `app/concepts/listing/operation.rb` should be some thing like...

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  class Create < Trailblazer::Operation
    def process(params)
      @model = Listing.create(params[:listing])
    end
  end
end
```